# Purpose of Func inside Lamda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, func

I am working on some code to get the Configuration section from the app config file. I have come across the following code in our files.

```
public ISection GetSection(string sectionName, System.Configuration.Configuration config)
{
  ISection section = (ISection) null;
  List<ISection> sections = this.Sections;
  if (sections != null)
    section = this.GetSectionInstance(sections.FirstOrDefault<ISection>((Func<ISection, bool>) (s => s.SectionName == sectionName)), config);
  return section;
}

private ISection GetSectionInstance(ISection freshSection, System.Configuration.Configuration config)
{
  ISection sectionInstance = (ISection) null;
  if (freshSection != null)
  {
    sectionInstance = freshSection.GetSection(config);
    sectionInstance?.CheckVersion();
  }
  return sectionInstance;
}
```

**Question:** I am not able to understand the syntax of the following line:

```
section = this.GetSectionInstance(sections.FirstOrDefault<ISection>((Func<ISection, bool>) (s => s.SectionName == sectionName)), config);
```

in the above line, I understand that in the lambda expression, we are trying to find the `FirstOrDefault` section which fulfills the condition `s.SectionName == sectionName` but I don't understand the purpose of the part `(Func<ISection, bool>)`. Are we trying to call a `Func` with signature `<ISection, bool>` on `s` where `s.SectionName == sectionName`?

Comment: Looks like generated code for me. There is no need to cast null, store sections, specify `<ISection>`  type of generic method, and manually specify lambda type

Comment: It's a cast of the type of the lambda `s => s.SectionName == sectionName` to a specific Func type. However, it should already be that type. You can also leave out the `<ISection>` that will be inferred by the compiler

Comment: @HansKeﬆing: In the lambda expression, `s` is of type `ISection`. How can it be casted to a `Func`? Maybe in this case, it doesn't matter to cast but could you provide a simple example where it is required to cast?

Comment: @skm It does not cast the `s` to a function rather the lambda expression. `(Func<ISection, bool>) (s => s.SectionName == sectionName)`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like generated code, because there are many implicit things specified explicitly. E.g:

```
ISection section = (ISection) null;
```

You don't need to init value with null and explicitly cast it to the `ISection`.  Also, it's not required to specify the generic type parameter of `FirstOrDefault<ISection>` or explicitly specify the type of lambda - all these things will be inferred by the compiler.

Eventually, this is an equivalent of:

```
public ISection GetSection(string sectionName, Configuration config)
{
   var sectionInstance = this.Sections
         ?.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SectionName == sectionName)
         ?.GetSection(config);

   sectionInstance?.CheckVersion();      
   return sectionInstance;
}
```

Comment: but there is no method definition corresponding to `GetSection(config)`